# Initial expression is of incorrect type, expected: Messaging.EmailFileAttachment but was: Attachment

Tags: apex, email, attachment, emailfileattachment

The below code gave me this error:

> Initial expression is of incorrect type, expected: Messaging.EmailFileAttachment but was: Attachment

Specific error line:

```
eMessage.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {eAttachment});
```

Entire code

```
   List<Attachment> attach = new List<Attachment>();
   Attachment eAttachment = new Attachment();

        if (email.binaryAttachments != null && email.binaryAttachments.size() > 0) {
                for (integer i = 0 ; i < email.binaryAttachments.size() ; i++) {
                    System.debug('Inside the Attachments');

                    eAttachment.ParentId = incomingCase.Id;
                    eAttachment.Name = email.binaryAttachments[i].filename;
                    eAttachment.Body = email.binaryAttachments[i].body;
                    attach.add(eAttachment);      
                 }

          }
Database.insert(attach,true);

     EmailMessage emailMsgObj = new EmailMessage();
     List<EmailMessage> emailMes = new List<EmailMessage>();

      if (email.binaryAttachments != null && email.binaryAttachments.size() > 0) {
                for (integer i = 0 ; i < email.binaryAttachments.size() ; i++) {
                    System.debug('Inside the Email');
                emailMsgObj.HtmlBody =  email.htmlBody;
                emailMsgObj.TextBody = email.plainTextBody;
                emailMsgObj.FromAddress = email.fromAddress;                
                emailMsgObj.FromName = email.fromName;
                emailMsgObj.Subject = email.subject;
                emailMsgObj.Incoming = true;
                emailMsgObj.ParentId = incomingCase.Id;

                emailMes.add(emailMsgObj);  

                }
      }


     Database.insert(emailMes,true);




  }
```

Comment: Please don't up and remove all of your code from the question.

Comment: Hi @Adrian Larson I am not deleting any post of mine

Comment: You continue to delete all of the content that makes your question useful to the community and provides context around provided answers. Please stop doing so.

Answer (score 2):

Your collection type is `List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment>`. That means each element within the collection (for example when you call `add()`) must be of the type **[`Messaging.EmailFileAttachment`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_attachment.htm)**. But instead, you are trying to add an element whose type is `Attachment`.

Instead, you should start with:

```
Messaging.EmailFileAttachment eAttach = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
```

You can see the documentation for this type [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_attachment.htm). You can set its `body`, `contentType`, `fileName`, and a few other properties as needed.

Comment: Am I still allowed to use Database.insert in Messaging.EmailFileAttachment???

Comment: No, you can't. You're not operating on the attachment anyway, currently. Only the message itself.

Comment: And we cant use attachement in Messaging.SingleEmailMessage?

Comment: No, you cannot.

Comment: Sorry I am still new in outbound messaging do u have sample code with that?